# MergeSort k arbitrary words in linear time

Tags: algorithms, sorting, efficiency, mergesort

Given $k$ arbitrary words, such as $\{\text{"fjqke"}, \text{"gbqig"}, \text{"a"}\}$, is there a way to mergesort these words in linear time so that the final output would be "abefgggijkq"? I tried to approach it by first sorting all the words independently and then merging the words into the final output, but sorting all the words takes $O(kn\log n)$ time.

Comment: Yes, if we assume the alphabet is fixed and finite, which is a reasonable and common assumption. Would you prefer an answer along this assumption?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes I'd love an answer with those assumptions!

Comment: @kelalaka, can you update your answer with the linear time algorithm under that assumption?

Comment: Updated with the finite case.

Comment: Note that the $O(k \cdot n \log n)$ bound is rather pessimistic. Expressing the runtime nicely in term of input size $n$ is a little fiddlesome, but the upper bound $O(k \cdot N \log N)$ with $N = \max \{n_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq k\}$ the largest word length is more informative already: if your words are roughly equal in length, you get $O(n \log n)$ sorting cost in total! (Merging comes on top.) Also, for long words, you can trivially parallelize the algorithm (in practice). In summary, I think the algorithm you reject is not as bad as you think, and probably quite good. And it's _simple_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General case:**

If there is a linear time sorting algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ for this problem, then one can divide a list into random parts, and use $\mathcal{A}$ to sort. But comparison based sorting has a lower bound $\Omega(n \log n)$. Therefore there is no such algorithm $\mathcal{A}$.

Note: Merge routine combines sorted arrays into one sorted array. There is a similar problem to your problem called [k-way merging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm), but that is also required sorted arrays. The complexity of k-way is $\mathcal{O}(n \log k)$

**Finite alphabet case:**

If we assume that the alphabet is finite, and in your case it seems only lower case letters then one can use the [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) algorithm.

Assuming that the total length of the words is $n$ and there are at most $t=26$ letters, the Counting sort can sort this array in $\mathcal{O}(n+t)$-time.

To achieve this with Counting sort, you need to convert this into an array and map the letters with an integer. And, call;

```
 countingSort(array,26)
```

The Counting sort is not [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm). The space requirement for this question is $\mathcal{O}(t)$

- Note 1: Counting sort is not a comparison based sorting algorithm, it uses counting, thus it is not bounded by the lower bound of the comparison based sorting algorithms.
- Note 2: Counting sort, also, can be implemented [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

Comment: Note that $k$ means something different in the question.

Comment: In practice, $k$ can be huge (think Unicode) so be careful with that.